PDF Viewer not showing up after compile
I'm new to vim. Using VimR.
I've managed to setup everything else correctly, but when I do :VimtexCompile, This returns VimTeX: Compilation completed, but no PDF viewer shows up.
I'm sorry if this is a stupid oversight, but I can't seem to find any similar problems.
Following is the log file output. I believe this should be working as expected.
{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./Physics1.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1171 strings out of 474116
 17745 string characters out of 5743683
 1929187 words of memory out of 5000000
 23582 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 563145 words of font info for 54 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,6n,65p,250b,197s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on Physics1.pdf (1 page, 85910 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 48 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 28 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

My /init.vim is as follows:
call plug#begin()

set encoding=utf-8

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='skim'
let g:vimtex_view_skim_sync = 1
let g:vimtex_view_skim_activate = 1



set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

Plug 'lotabout/skim'

Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'


call plug#end()

This is my :VimtexInfo.
System info:
  OS: macOS 14.5 (23F79)
  Vim version: NVIM v0.10.0
  Has clientserver: true
  Servername: /var/folders/c_/mf63463d1770jjvqcmv2jc840000gn/T/nvim.raifa/0nTe5O/nvim.39939.0

VimTeX project: Physics1
  base: Physics1.vim
  root: /Users/raifa/Documents/Notes
  tex: 
  main parser: fallback current file
  document class: 
  packages: amsbsy amsgen amsmath amsopn amstext
  compiler: latexmk
    engine: -pdf
    options:
      -verbose
      -file-line-error
      -synctex=1
      -interaction=nonstopmode
    callback: 1
    continuous: 1
    executable: latexmk
    job: 
      jobid: 8
      output: /var/folders/c_/mf63463d1770jjvqcmv2jc840000gn/T/nvim.raifa/0nTe5O/0
      cmd: max_print_line=2000 latexmk -verbose -file-line-error -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -pdf -pvc -pvctimeout- -view=none -e '$compiling_cmd = ($compiling_cmd ? $compiling_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_compiling"' -e '$success_cmd = ($success_cmd ? $success_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_success"' -e '$failure_cmd = ($failure_cmd ? $failure_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_failure"' 'Physics1.vim'
      pid: 40541
  viewer: Skim
  qf method: LaTeX logfile


any help would be appreciated. I'm using skim as Zathura did not work for me.

Welcome! Is a PDF produced? Can you open it manually in Skim? I know it says it wrote one, but is it where is should be and display as you expect? That's not the complete log file, is it?

@cfr Yes. It's produced within the same folder of the .vim file, and I am able to open it manually with skim.
Display is also as expected.

It looks like you are running neovim, so can you run :checkhealth? Vimtex has hooks to health.vim that would tell you if you made any configuration mistakes. // What happens if you just do :VimtexView?

@WillieWong :checkhealth is as below: terminal ~

ERROR command failed: infocmp -L
infocmp: environment variable TERM not set External Tools ~
WARNING ripgrep not available - WARNING pstree is not available

ADVICE:

vimtex#view#inverse_search is better if pstree is available.






@WillieWong oh! :VimtexView actually shows the pdf as long as skim is booted up in the first place. I'm still having to save manually each time for the pdf to be refreshed,  which isnt great

@Raifa: you always have to save manually with Vimtex. If you have the compiler running, it is only triggered when the file on disk is changed, which only happens when you save the Vim buffer to file. Or do you mean something else by "I'm still having to save manually each time for the PDF to be refreshed."

The fact that Skim works when it is already running, but not when it is not already running is to me important. I suggest you instead of posting a question here, try asking on the Vimtex issues page https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues The plug-in author is very willing to help in my experience.

@WillieWong Thanks for the info. Will do.
